# CSS/Jquery: Peel corner on hover and fold in half on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Saw this cool 3x3 grid on this site and cant seem to re-create the animation it has.

The image folds a bit on hover and folds completely in half on a click.

Reference: http://doyouimpress.com/

I've tried doing something similar in CSS however the :active psuedo selector won't open the page completely unless you hold click. Would I only be able to re-create this animation w jquery?

Here's what I've done so far (webkit only): http://jsfiddle.net/JDH9/4wrnf/8/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="test">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -200px 0 0 -100px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
#test {
    position: relative;
}
#test div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
#left {
    background: grey;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
}
#center {
    background: grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}
#test:hover #left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
#test:active #left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: I feel like I've seen this exact question before.

Comment: the `:active` css3 which is doing the half fold can be included in a a class `.halffold{ ...}` and the same class cab be added on a click event callback defined in jquery `$('#left').on('click',function() { if(this.hasClass('halffold')) this.addClass('halffold'); else this.removeClass('halffold');} )`

Comment: i was thinking to do the same changes on your fiddle, not sure its not working as you have mentioned, anyway the logic what i have mentioned should work, unless their is any specific flow which i have missed

Comment: A bit of googling I found a codepen example: http://codepen.io/benske/pen/jpdco

Comment: Thanks for the response. @ Dave - thats awesome! I checked codepen for a couple days and couldnt find anything similar. thanks. is the fold on click working for you? it doesn't seen to work for me?

Comment: @user3657808 Sorry I didn't read your post closely enough.  It looks like the same code base since the class names are the same.  But I don't think the full fold on click is in that demo.

Comment: I would have thought this portion of the code would have been for the full fold but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: .origami.origami-open .kami-wrapper.kami-wrapper-first {
  z-index: 10; 
}
.origami.origami-open .kami-wrapper.kami-wrapper-bis {
  z-index: 20;
}

.origami.origami-open .kami-peek-mask.kami-peek-mask-first {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear 0ms; transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear 0ms; 
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

Comment: <blink>
       .origami.origami-open .kami-mask-bis{
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0px; 
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1200ms ease-out 233.33333333333334ms; transition: -webkit-transform 1200ms ease-out 233.33333333333334ms;
}
    </blink>